# TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;message&#39; of undefined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, uuid

I am getting an error of `TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;message&#39; of undefined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;` on a `Postman` `post` request for a `express` server code.

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const {v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid');
const app = express();

// Middleware for data on post request
app.use(express.json({extended: false}));


// Data
const todos = [
    {
        message: "Buy tea", 
        id: 1
    }, 
    {
        message: "Buy wrp for lunch",
        id: 2
    },
    {
        message: "Play game",
        id: 3
    }
];

/* --------- API ---------- */
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json(todos);
})

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const newtodo = {
        message: res.body.message,
        id: uuidv4()
    }
    todos.push(newtodo);
    res.status(201).json(todos);
})



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
} );
```

On `Headers` I have `Key Content-type` `Value application/json`. But I keep getting the error. The screenshot is down below:

[image]

Can't seem to pinpoint the issue. `Message` is defined on my `server.js` file.

Comment: could it be that `res.body` is undefined, therefore has no property called `message` - perhaps you meant  `req.body.task` ... coz that's what you're sending

Comment: @Bravo actually I was testing with `task` as property instead of `message`. So wrong screenshot was uploaded. Corrected it now. "could it be that res.body is undefined," - but I have the `body` on `postman` defined. You can see that on the screenshot.

Comment: yes, you have set the body of the ***request*** - I did say that - but you're trying to read the body of the ***response*** (they are not the same thing)

Comment: @Bravo Yes, you were right. Please add that as the answer.

Comment: as far as I'm concerned it was a typo - surely you didn't deliberately use response instead of request when reading the request

Comment: Typos are bad here. So I will delete the question instead.

Comment: Doesn't allow me to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here should be `req.body.message` instead `res.body.message`

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
const newtodo = {
    message: req.body.message,
    id: uuidv4()
}
todos.push(newtodo);
res.status(201).json(todos);
})
```

If I'm wrong you can use optional chaining like this `res?.body?.message`.

[Javascript Optional Chaining](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining)